# Differing kernel versions for 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the same OS?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a laptop with side by side installation of 32-bit and 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04. I have just noticed that I have different kernel versions on these OS (see logs below):

- The 32 bit has kernel: 3.19.0-58
- The 64 bit has kernel: 4.2.0-35

My question is - Is this as expected/normal? I can see from the logs below that the 32-bit version claims the kernel from `linux-generic-lts-vivid`, and the 64-bit version from `linux-generic-lts-wily` (neither of which are `-trusty`, and are in fact later than it - but both come from `trusty-security`?!).

I really cannot remember if I had installed something that caused this state. What would be the recommended way to get them both to the same kernel version?

Logs, 32-bit:

```
+ uname -a
Linux mypc 3.19.0-58-generic #64~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 19:05:42 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
+ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS \n \l

+ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
+ apt-show-versions -r linux
intel-linux-graphics-installer:i386 1.1.0-0intel1 installed: No available version in archive
libselinux1:i386/trusty-updates 2.2.2-1ubuntu0.1 uptodate
linux-firmware:all/trusty-security 1.127.20 uptodate
linux-generic-lts-vivid:i386/trusty-security 3.19.0.58.41 uptodate
linux-headers-3.19.0-58:all/trusty-security 3.19.0-58.64~14.04.1 uptodate
linux-headers-3.19.0-58-generic:i386/trusty-security 3.19.0-58.64~14.04.1 uptodate
linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid:i386/trusty-security 3.19.0.58.41 uptodate
linux-image-3.19.0-58-generic:i386/trusty-security 3.19.0-58.64~14.04.1 uptodate
linux-image-extra-3.19.0-58-generic:i386/trusty-security 3.19.0-58.64~14.04.1 uptodate
linux-image-generic-lts-vivid:i386/trusty-security 3.19.0.58.41 uptodate
linux-libc-dev:i386/trusty-security 3.13.0-85.129 uptodate
linux-sound-base:all/trusty 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4 uptodate
pptp-linux:i386/trusty 1.7.2-7 uptodate
syslinux:i386/trusty 3:4.05+dfsg-6+deb8u1 uptodate
syslinux-common:all/trusty 3:4.05+dfsg-6+deb8u1 uptodate
syslinux-legacy:i386/trusty 2:3.63+dfsg-2ubuntu5 uptodate
util-linux:i386/trusty-updates 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7 uptodate
```

Logs, 64-bit:

```
+ uname -a
Linux mypc 4.2.0-35-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 16:37:35 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
+ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS \n \l

+ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
+ apt-show-versions -r linux
libselinux1:amd64/trusty-updates 2.2.2-1ubuntu0.1 uptodate
libselinux1:i386/trusty-updates 2.2.2-1ubuntu0.1 uptodate
linux-firmware:all/trusty-security 1.127.20 uptodate
linux-generic-lts-wily:amd64/trusty-security 4.2.0.35.28 uptodate
linux-headers-4.2.0-35:all/trusty-security 4.2.0-35.40~14.04.1 uptodate
linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic:amd64/trusty-security 4.2.0-35.40~14.04.1 uptodate
linux-headers-generic-lts-wily:amd64/trusty-security 4.2.0.35.28 uptodate
linux-image-4.2.0-35-generic:amd64/trusty-security 4.2.0-35.40~14.04.1 uptodate
linux-image-extra-4.2.0-35-generic:amd64/trusty-security 4.2.0-35.40~14.04.1 uptodate
linux-image-generic-lts-wily:amd64/trusty-security 4.2.0.35.28 uptodate
linux-libc-dev:amd64/trusty-security 3.13.0-85.129 uptodate
linux-signed-generic-lts-wily:amd64/trusty-security 4.2.0.35.28 uptodate
linux-signed-image-4.2.0-35-generic:amd64/trusty-security 4.2.0-35.40~14.04.1 uptodate
linux-signed-image-generic-lts-wily:amd64/trusty-security 4.2.0.35.28 uptodate
linux-sound-base:all/trusty 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4 uptodate
pptp-linux:amd64/trusty 1.7.2-7 uptodate
syslinux:amd64/trusty 3:4.05+dfsg-6+deb8u1 uptodate
syslinux-common:all/trusty 3:4.05+dfsg-6+deb8u1 uptodate
syslinux-legacy:amd64/trusty 2:3.63+dfsg-2ubuntu5 uptodate
util-linux:amd64/trusty-updates 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7 uptodate
```

Comment: It is not related to 64 or 32 bit at all. LTS versions have optional kernels. It depends on which image you initially install from, e.g. 14.04.4 or 14.04.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install kernel 4.2 to any 14.04.x release by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

It is not related to 32 or 64 bit versions.